# How to best deal with the Coronavirus situation?

Tags: discussion

How can we as a community deal with the influx of Coronavirus-19 questions coming in.

We all realize that the present situation seems surreal to many Christians.

What is the best way to deal with this present situation which is rapidly changing and evolving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't normally allow for open ended quote request questions, but maybe this could be a special exception. We could ask what Christians have written or said during plagues and pandemics of the past. Other questions can be closed as duplicates of it or deleted.

Maybe something like

> What have Christians taught during past plagues and pandemics?

Maybe make it a wiki question?

When this is all over it can be closed or locked.

Comment: Good idea, but some might be disheartened to find that there's a lot of "God's wrath outpouring, repent!" quotes. Even today, that's not unheard of. There's already been a number calling it punishment on group X. The Scripture itself has plagues and disease as God's punishments, everywhere from Moses and the Egyptians to the End in Revelation.

Answer (score 4):

Flag them and I'll put "rapidly changing event" on it.

I don't know how we can appease everyone, but since people can't necessarily seek spiritual guidance in the normal ways, we should probably feel a little more at ease to answer in the comments.  We'll clean up eventually.

Questions that require God to answer should still be closed.

With God's grace this will all be over soon.